# Suggestions with designing a context free grammar (CFG)

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, automata, formal-languages

I am trying to create a CFG for:

> L = {az<sup>n</sup> |a ∈ {x, y}* and n = number of x’s in a or number of y’s in a}

I am not sure how or where to begin.

I understand the language description to be a string of x and y's followed by a string of z's there the number of z's must be the same of either x or y.

Examples: `{xxyxyyxxyzzzzz, yxyxyxyyyzzzzzz, etc...}`

This is my "best" solution:

```
S => xSz | ySz | ϵ
```

I know this is wrong because z produces the same number of x and y combined, rather than x or y individually.

EDIT:

I think this is the answer, but I am not sure. It seems to work.

```
S => xSz | ySz | xS | yS | ϵ
```

Edit:

Well that doesn't work, as it accept invalid strings too...

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your question can be decomposed into union of two languages

> L=L<sub>1</sub> U L<sub>2</sub>

L<sub>1</sub> is (x<sup>i</sup>,y<sup>j</sup>)z<sup>k</sup> where i==k and L<sub>2</sub> suffices j==k

In other words, L<sub>1</sub> contains equal x's and z's while L<sub>2</sub> contains equal y's and z's.

Hence, for L<sub>1</sub>, we can compose the CFG as

> S<sub>1</sub> => A<sub>1</sub>S<sub>1</sub>z | B<sub>1</sub>
>
> A<sub>1</sub> => A<sub>1</sub>B<sub>1</sub> | B<sub>1</sub>A<sub>1</sub> | x
>
> B<sub>1</sub> => yB<sub>1</sub> | e

The first 2 productions ensure that it spawns the same number of x and z;

Similarly, we can construct the CFG for L<sub>2</sub>:

> S<sub>2</sub> => A<sub>2</sub>S<sub>2</sub>z | B<sub>2</sub>
>
> A<sub>2</sub> => A<sub>2</sub>B<sub>2</sub> | B<sub>2</sub>A<sub>2</sub> | y
>
> B<sub>2</sub> => xB<sub>2</sub> | e

Finally, we can union those productions to get the answer:

> S => S<sub>1</sub> | S<sub>2</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer:

```
S = A | B
A = C xSz | C
B = D ySz | D
C = yC | e
D = xD | e
```

Not sure if it can be reduced though

Comment: Do you have a proof in mind (that this generates L)?